# SSH to remote server via a Jump Host

Tags: superputty

I want to SSH to a remote server via the jump host. But my requirement is, use the superputty to ssh. is there a away to use "extra putty arguments" in superputty , using plink/proxycmd ..etc ?
Can somebody help me on this ?

Windows desktop (supperputty) ---> JumpHost ---> Remote server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzq30.png)
Let me provide you some details to get an actual idea of what I am doing right now. As I mentioned in the attached image, I used to SSH to JumpHost using ssh authentication PPK key and then I login to the other remote node. for the remote nodes also i have to use their ppk key.

So likewise, I want to pass those parameters as "extra putty arguments" to access the remote node directly.

Thank you
Luke

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `plink.exe` program (which comes with a full PuTTY installation), you can use:

```
-proxycmd "plink -nc %host:%port user@jumphost.example.com"
```

(This is the equivalent of `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost` in OpenSSH.)

Comment: Thank you, I will try and let you know the outcome.

Comment: sorry it didnt work for me . I am able to pass the certificate key for the jumphost to connect. But the other paramters , didnt work as u guided.